# Check whether the number is in array or not with minimum complexity

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

An array is given and the distance between any two consequent elements is one(+1 or -1). We are given with a number. How can we check whether the number is in array or not with minimum complexity.

Comment: Keep your array sorted, then you can achieve a search in O(log n) by using binary search.

Comment: Good question. What’s your attempt? (To clarify: We will gladly help you, but we will **not** do your homework.)

Comment: @cli_hlt For only one query, it will take more time to sort than it would take for a simple linear search.

Comment: If the array is sorted and there are no duplicates, then x[0] is the minimum and x[0]+x.length-1 is the maximum value.

Comment: @Dukeling of course...but the "only one query" case is exceptionally rare, I suppose.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sir it is an Interview question

Comment: @Dukeling Certain languages such as Java provide collections which allow sorting on adding (check Sorted Set), so I guess that the binary search approach would be still good?

Comment: @npinti "An array is given" and constructing a sorted set will also take O(n log n).

Comment: The obvious question is whether the array is sorted or not and whether there are duplicates in the array.

Comment: @LarsEbert The array is not sorted since the distance between any two consequent elements can either be +1 or -1.

Comment: So the answer is O(n log n).

Comment: @cli_hlt No, that’s not optimal.

Comment: A very nice quiz question. A _terrible_ interview question, IMO.

Comment: Lack of attempt at solution results in downvote.

Answer (score 8):

You can do sort of a binary search.

If the element we're looking for is between the first and last element we know the element appears in the array and we can stop.

If it's not, check the minimum and maximum possible values that can appear in the array by finding the difference between the first and last element, subtracting the number of elements, dividing this by two and subtracting / adding this from / to the minimum / maximum of the two.

More explicitly:

```
temp = abs(arr[left] - arr[right]) - (left - right)
minPossible = min(arr[left], arr[right]) - 2*temp
maxPossible = max(arr[left], arr[right]) + 2*temp
```

Repeat recursively, splitting the array in halves (or splitting [as Daniel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676618/1711796)).

**Why the above gives the minimum / maximum possible:**

Think of it as follows: You need a number of elements equal to the difference between the left and the right to get from the one to the other. Beyond that, for each step you take down / up, you need to take that step up / down again.

Still unfortunately not less than O(n) worst case.

**Here's why O(n) worst case can't be beat:**

(Similar to [David's proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676942/1711796)).

Example input = `[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]`

Assume we're looking for 2.

It's obviously not there, but what if one of the 0's were to be changed to a 2? We need to check **every** zero. Once we skip even a single one, that one could've been the 2.

Thus we **have to** check at least 1/2 of the elements, thus it's still O(n/2) = O(n).

Comment: It wasn’t downvoted. It’s also quite clever – it may be more efficient than Daniel’s solution, even.

Comment: It really looks more efficient than my solution, because it takes more advantage of the available information. I no longer think my answer is the optimal solution. I will edit that part of it, but leave it for completeness.

Comment: My worst case also checks half the numbers. I still don't know if we have a tie or you win, in the average case. After picturing the problem graphically, though, I think your algorithm wins.

Answer (score 5):

You can save checking some (probably most) of the elements, with the following algorithm.

If your number is 85 and the first number of the array is 100, you can skip (15-1) = 14 numbers (of course 15 is the distance between 100 and 85) because the closest they can get to 85 is 99, 98, 97, ..., 86. So you just check the 15th number. If that number is not 85, keep repeating the same algorithm. This lets you jump through the array, which is still O(N) but probably faster in clock time than just checking one by one.

A worst case scenario would be like: I am looking for 85.

- The first number is 86. I can't skip any number because (1-1) = 0 and the next number could very well be 85.
- I check the next number. It is 87. Ah, now I can skip *one* number because (2-1) = 1; the next number, which I am skipping, might be 88 or 86, but never 85.
- I check the *other* next number and it is 86.
- Everything goes on to be the same because the array is actually 86, 87, 86, 87, 86, 87, ... so I end up checking all the 87's, which are nearly half the numbers.

I considered this to be the optimal algorithm until I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676785/96780).

Comment: Almost perfect. Could only be improved by giving an exact probabilistic performance analysis. But that’s hard. ;-)

Comment: I think this is rather clever. But why is it still O(n)? Isn't it - statistically speaking - less complex? O(n) would only apply if you had to check every element, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Lars Ebert: You are wrong. `O(n)` doesn't mean that you check every element; it means that, in the worst case, you check *at most* a number of elements that is proportional to `n` (i.e., a constant multiple of `n`).

Comment: @Jason Ah okay. I did not know that. As I said, I am not a mathematican. But in this case, I agree that the minimum complexity is O(n) and can not be reduced.

Comment: It is O(n), just O(a smaller n) :-)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has expected cell-probe complexity Ω(n), so a sublinear algorithm is not going to happen. Consider the possible inputs

```
210101010...10
012101010...10
010121010...10
...
010101010...12
```

with equal probability. Find the 2. By Yao's lemma, for a fixed input distribution, the best randomized algorithm is no better than the best deterministic algorithm. Prior to finding the 2, all of the inputs that haven't been ruled out look identical. Thus, every correct deterministic algorithm must probe the 0 locations in some order, with an expected n/4 (or thereabouts) locations probed until the 2 is located.

Comment: I’m not sure Yao’s lemma is relevant here: it gives a lower bound for *randomised* algorithms, not for deterministic ones. I think you’re applying it the wrong way round (i.e. you are trying to infer a lower bound of a deterministic algorithm by considering the distribution that a randomised algorithm would have to work with).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I was lowerbounding the performance of randomized algorithms, of which deterministic algorithms is a subclass. Yao's principle is that, if the input distribution is chosen without regard to the algorithm, then it suffices without loss of generality to consider the behavior of a deterministic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the complexity cannot be less than O(N). That said I would go through the whole array .

Whenever either

- the read value minus the desired number is, in absolute value, greater than the number of elements which follow OR
- the read value equals the desired value

i would "break" the algorithm saying "yes" as an answer.

As a default, the answer is "no"! :)

Comment: That’s not optimal, as you’ll already have found the actual number between them.

Comment: True, but you would still have to check all values to verify that it is not in there!

Comment: Actutally, the complexity can be less than O(N) if the number is not contained in the array! If you check the first value and see that it's distance to the number in question is bigger than the length of the array, you have proven the number not to be inside the array. I am not a mathmatican, so someone else would have to calculate the complexity of this, sorry!

Comment: @LarsEbert good point!!! The complexity, however, is still O(N), you don't compute complexity on the basis of a special case: it's a worst case analysis. It would be like saying that ordering a vector can be O(N) if the array is already ordered (since you only need to check if it is).

Comment: @Lars … and that’s the sketch for the optimal solution. The *expected*, amortised time will still be O(N) though, unless we know specifics about the distribution of either the array or the test numbers.

Comment: @DanielDaranas “which are the only correct terms, by the way” – nonsense. If that were the case nobody would ever use a hash table, or quicksort.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: But if you loop through the array, and it is not contained, the complexity is O(n), unless you find an element which is further away from our target than the array is long. If the target is contained, the complexity is smallet than O(n), as you statistically only have to check half the elements until you find it. So O(n) is the extreme in this case and in most cases you get away with a complexity less than O(n).

Comment: @Kornad I changed my comment to an answer, sorry. I omitted the confuse terms you replied to.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I would agree with Daniel Daranas. Notice that he was speeking about complexity, not about how fast an algorithm is. So, your "implication" (If that were the case nobody would ever use a hash table, or quicksort.) is not correct

Comment: @Stefano It’s not a question about agreement. It’s plain *wrong*. And you are confusing something, because “complexity” by itself means nothing. We are speaking about *runtime complexity* – i.e. about a measure of “how fast an algorithm is”. And, yes, as a consequence my implication *is* correct.

Comment: @Lars You may get away with less than N comparisons – but less than O(N)? No.

Comment: @KonradRudolph algorithm complexity is not a measure of "how fast an algorithm is". If you are not convinced about this try to learn something about Strassen algorithm for matrix multiplication and inversion, it's quite funny

Comment: @Stefano How does the Strassen algorithm contradict what I said? And yes, I know about performance vs. number of operations etc. but that’s hardly the point here. The point is that we are *not* always interested in the worst-case complexity, if we know (or can even prove) that the worst case is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you look for a value `v` in the array. If at a given position `i` the value `a[i]` is `v-d` the value we are looking for is at least at a distance of `d` cells from `i`. So you can skip the cells in between, because the can at best have the values `v-d+1`, `v-d+2` and so on. So here's a sloppy recursive algo for you:

```
template <class ForwardIter, class T>
ForwardIter find_in_singlestep_range(ForwardIter first, ForwardIter last, T val) {
  if (first == last) return last;
  if (*first == val) return first;

  auto max_diff = last-first;
  auto diff = make_signed<T>{val} - make_signed<T>{*first};
  if (diff < 0) diff = -diff;
  if (diff > max_diff) return last;

  return find_in_singlestep_range(first+diff, last, val);
}
```

Complexity:
You will get at most 1/2*N +1 comparisons, since assuming you never encounter the element, the worst case can be that diff is 1,2,2,2,2, so you skip every second element. (if diff was 2, the next diff can be only 2 or 4.)

Maybe you have better complexity if you do a binary search: you can skip search in a subarray, if the difference of the subarray's middle element to `val` is greater than half the subarray size.

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference between elements is 1 (either +1 or -1) then any number between `min(array)` and `max(array)` will be in the array. If you cache min and max, then the first search is `O(N)` and every other will be `O(1)`.

If elements of the array are fractions instead of integer, then there is an addtional pre-requisite test, `fractionPart(min(array))-fractionPart(number)==0`